# 'where' property in one of 2 number ranges

Tags: c#, linq

Hope someone can help me with a LINQ query.

I am building a list from a larger list of store items where a property is in one of 2 number ranges.

```
ListOfItems = store.Items.Where((p => p.Type > 159 && p.Type < 169) || (p.Type > 220 && p.Type < 241)).ToList()
```

However, I get error:

> name 'p' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Watch your matching parentheses.  You forgot an open/ left off a closing paren.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you had a parenthesis in the wrong place. Try:

```
ListOfItems = store.Items.Where(p => (p.Type > 159 && p.Type < 169) || (p.Type > 220 && p.Type < 241)).ToList()
```